# How do I grep and filter logs for date and a particular field

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, grep

My logs will have some lines with below format

`test/blah.log.32:30141:2019-08-12 16:40:09,839 com.test.service.testService [P1-7XX8] INFO  testMethod(): userId: 12345XX, someOtherId: 12345XXXCCCDDD, blah, blah...., _someType=V, blah, blah, blah....`

how do I grep for data that contains text `_someType=V` and then filter date and userId out of it. My final result should be

`2019-08-12 16:40:09,839-12345XX`

I could do a grep with `grep -Hn '_someType=V'` but failing to filter the data.

Comment: File text starts with `30141:` or with `test/blah.log.32:` ?

Comment: @anubhava most likely with `2019-08-12 16:40:09,839 com.test...` : `test/blah.log.32` would be the file name and `30141` the line number, outputted respectively by `grep`'s `-H` and `-n`

Comment: chain multiple greps togehter? `grep '_someType=V file | grep 2019-09-10' | grep userID` ? Use the `-o` option to limit the output to  your search target.

Comment: @shellter that would work if the two pieces of data OP wanted to retrieve were consecutive. Since they aren't you can't select both of them with `-o`, you'd have to use `sed` to remove what's between the two pieces of data

Comment: @Aaron : I'm reading the sample log data as one continuous line. But ... too bad the data is not better presented so there aren't differences in interpretation. But I like both solutions below and hope they work for O.P. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I'm not sure what you mean by the continuous line, but once you've extracted a first piece of data with `grep -o` you can't pipe that further into another `grep -o` to extract another piece of data that isn't present in the first one : the second `grep` will only receive the first piece of data rather than the whole line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the output of your `grep` command into `sed` to transform the whole line into the two relevant pieces of data :

```
grep '_someType=V' | sed -E 's/^([^ ]* [^ ]*).*userId: ([^ ]*).*/\1-\2/'
```

The `sed` `s`ubstitution command captures the two first "words" of the line corresponding to the date into a first capturing group and the word that follows `userId` into a second one, matching the whole line to replace it with the content of the two capturing groups separated by a dash.

If the order between `_someType=V` and `userId` is always the same, you can do without the `grep`, for instance if `_someType=V` always appears after the `userId`:

```
sed -nE 's/^([^ ]* [^ ]*).*userId: ([^ ]*).*_someType=V.*/\1-\2/p'
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk -v s='userId: ' '/_someType=V/ && match($0, s "[^, ]+") {
   print $1, $2 "-" substr($0, RSTART+length(s), RLENGTH-length(s))
}' file
```

```
2019-08-12 16:40:09,839-12345XX
```